# Kendall tau for censored data

Tags: python, statistics, correlation

Is there a python module that has the generalised Kendall tau estimator for censored data? What I am looking for specifically is from section 3b of [this paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1986ApJ...306..490I&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf). It has been implemented in FORTRAN as part of the ASURV package but is there a python version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not exactly based on the paper you mention.

https://github.com/sflury/kendall

This is based on the two-variable correlation formalism of Akrita & Siebert.